# Application Exit unknowingly in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

The **application gets exit unknowingly with out catching the exception**. We have implemented **try catch functionality** in the Application. I couldn't catch the exception in App unhandled exception.

For example, we have sub menu screen in our application, while clicking on the sub menu content listing screen is displayed. But some times continuously working on sub menu screen, the application gets exit with out unknowingly.
Kindly suggest.

Sub menu page sample code:
I have two stack panel and each having same set of codes for navigating to other pages.

```
private void stk_searchworkorder_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/MMS/WOSearch.xaml?History=false", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
       catch (System.Reflection.TargetException ex) { }   catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown exception", app.glbExceptionTitle, MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }

    private void stk_searchworkorder_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SolidColorBrush br = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 40, 40, 40));
            stk_searchworkorder.Background = br;
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.TargetException ex) { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown exception", app.glbExceptionTitle, MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }

    private void stk_searchworkorder_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SolidColorBrush br = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            stk_searchworkorder.Background = br;
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.TargetException ex) { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown exception", app.glbExceptionTitle, MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely running out of memory. The WP8 operating system *WILL* terminate your app, without your app being able to catch any exception, if your application's memory usage goes over its limit.

Limits are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

For troubleshooting, you can query your memory usage within your app using the [DeviceExtendedProperties class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). At the end of the day, you will want to make sure your app never goes over 150.

You application likely has a memory leak.

Comment: How to avoid the memory leak? Note:Frequently we are calling WCF service from application to assign/save data collection to online server.

Comment: Kindly suggest on application exit and memory leak. How to overcome the issues

Comment: This is not a question that can be answered easily. You will want to start with the Windows Phone Application Analysis tool provided with the SDK, which will point you, among other things, to objects with large or growing (leaking) memory allocations. Tool url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look in your App.xaml.cs file. There is an Application_UnhandledException method. Make sure you do proper handling of exceptions in this method, and if you set e.Handled = true, it won't crash the application thereafter.

Note that this doesn't capture EVERY possible unhandled exception - for example, OutofMemoryException will still crash the app, but it does catch a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something but wouldn't you just use NavigationService.Navigate instead of (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate?

Comment: In most cases (likely including this), yes, you can do that, but there are cases where you can't - for instance, if you're in a utility function that doesn't have access to NavigationService. I would imagine that since these are UI component event handlers that that's not the case, though.